# Does stackoverflow give badge for site down

Tags: discussion, badges

A few minutes ago site was down. And I see it for the first time in all time. This surprised me. And I think many users. Question: Does the site give a badge for what we became eyewitnesses. And could see it? :))

[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't give badges, a) it happens more often than you'd think, b) if the site is offline how would they know you checked the site to give a badge

Comment: @Nick this screenshot is proof :)

Comment: Proof that you get a canned message. Not that the backend functionality is up and running to acknowledge the "achievement".

Comment: ... but why? If the site is down, they'll have bigger issues than awarding _badges_. There's quite a few hits per minute IIRC, so that also means a lot of badges and a lot of manual work for a participation trophy that's probably backed by a certain pointless meme that programmers can't do any work while SO is down. It died - it happens from time to time. There's no need to hand out badges for _that_, nor is it a good use of the already limited resources SO has

Comment: Could we have a badge when SO is up again too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Overflow gives badges for things it wants you to learn about the site or things it wants to encourage you to do, for example question reviews.

There's nothing you can learn (other than patience) when you see the Stack Overflow is down screen and nothing that you're encouraged to do other than wait.

Less importantly, how would you claim the badge? If it's via a screenshot we could all copy the one you've provided in this question and claim it whether or not we'd experienced the site being down.

Comment: Robert, you're foiling my evil plan to get this badge :(!